# Checkbox in the Datagridview not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am using a `Datagridview` in a winform and using Virtual Mode to populate the unbound data.

I have a checkbox header, with a static checkbox. When I click on the checkbox, all the checkbox status is toggled.

However, the check status is not refreshed. I need to hover over the `Datagridview` to refresh the status of the checkbox.

When earlier, the Virtual mode was set to false, I was not having this problem. Any idea, if I am missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

What worked for me:

```
this.dataGridView2.CurrentCell = null (thanks silent winter)
```

or

```
this.dataGridView2.RefreshEdit();
this.dataGridView2.Refresh();
```

Comment: Please don't add "the answers X and Y worked for me" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying that something is helpful.

Comment: Noted. The second one is a combination of 2 solutions tho.

Comment: Not sure why adding the call to `RefreshEdit()` before calling `Refresh()` works, but it seems to have fixed the similar problem I was experiencing.

Answer (score 6):

Just to note, the Refresh() didn't work for me.  I had to use `this.dataGridView2.CurrentCell = null`

[DataGridView -Value does not gets saved if selection is not lost from a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963601/datagridview-value-does-not-gets-saved-if-selection-is-not-lost-from-a-cell)

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer for future reference and for users who might be facing similar issues.

Adding `this.dataGridView2.Refresh();` in the checkbox changed eventhandler fixed the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox on the header is a child-control of the datagridview use the RefreshEdit method to refresh the results. I had the same issue recently.