# Programmatically setting a datagridview cell value, but dataAdapter.Update() does not update the DB

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I am programmatically updating a certain cell in a DGV and when I call my UpdateDGV(), it does not update to the DB. However, if I manually update that cell, which is a combo box and bound(DB using a DataTable), and fire off my update function, it works fine. It almost seems that a specific property for the combo box has not been set to modified or something similar to that. See code below:

```
private void CheckForPendingStatus()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagriview1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells["status_cd"].Value.ToString().Equals(Constants.pending_status))// 'P'
            {
                row.Selected = true;
                row.Cells["status_cd"].Value = "I";
                UpdateDGV();
                break;
            }
        }
}
private void UpdateDgv()
    {
        try
        {
            // Update the database with the user's changes.
            dataAdapter.Update((DataTable)BindingSource1.DataSource);
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentNullException ArgNullExc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UpdateDgv - ArgumentNullException: error message: " + ArgNullExc.Message);
        }
        catch (System.InvalidOperationException InvalidOperExc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UpdateDgv - InvalidOperationException: error message: " + InvalidOperExc.Message);
        }
        catch (System.SystemException SysExc)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UpdateDgv - SystemException: error message: " + SysExc.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UpdateDgv - Exception: error message: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I've tried to see if there are any changes using the code below:

```
DataTable changes = ((DataTable)BindingSource1.DataSource).GetChanges();

if (changes != null)
    {
        //Update....
    }
```

As noted above, when programmatically making the change, 'changes' is null but not null when you physically click on the combo box and change the value.

Would I need to also set the value member and display member in the combo box for that cell? Will try to figure it out and see.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/963601

Comment: Code dataGridViewDtl.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit); worked great, thank you very much Robert.

Comment: You can find the answer with link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963601/datagridview-value-does-not-gets-saved-if-selection-is-not-lost-from-a-cell